How to plot the sum of a sequence with PGFPlots and tikzmath?
I tried to plot the sum of a sequence and faced some troubles. The following simplified code, plotting the sums of binomial coefficients, still shows the same problem.
    \documentclass{standalone}
    
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    
    \begin{document}
      
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      evaluate = {
        function a(\n, \k) { return \n!/(\k! * (\n - \k)!); };
        function s(\n, \k) {
          if \k < 0 then {
            return 0;
           } else {
            return a(\n, \k) + s(\n, \k - 1);
          };
        };
        function b(\n) { return s(\n, \n); }; % This does not work.
        %function b(\n) { return 2^\n; }; % This does work.
      }
    ]
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
      xmin = 0,
      xmax = 10,
      ymin = 1e-1,
      ymax = 1e4,
    ]
      \addplot[
        samples at = {0, 1, ..., 10},
        only marks,
      ]{ b(x) };
    \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}

This gives me the following error message.
  ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
  <to be read again> 

Everything works fine if I switched to another definition of b(\n). So the problem must be the definition of that recursively defined function s(\n, \k). But what's wrong with it? How can it be fixed?

I can't reproduce the problem, for me also the recursive definition works without errors.

@Marijn Thank you for your comment. I checked my environment, rather than codes, and it shows me \pgfplotsversion was 1.14 and pdflatex is of TeX Live 2017. So it's fairly out-dated. Could you tell us about your version information? Maybe all I need is just updating.

That seems likely indeed. I use pgfplots v1.18 (TeX Live 2022), which is also outdated but much less so compared to your version :)

I still don't upgrading my local environment yet, but I tried the same code on Overleaf, with PGFPlots 1.18 and TeX Live 2024. My code works there too :) So I couldn't point out where is wrong, but it's definitely something related to environment and not the code per se.

Updating TeX Live to the latest solves the problem as indicated in the comments. Thank you Marjin! The original code per se is correct.

Good that the issue got resolved. Let's close the question as 'solved by an update' then.

Accepting my own answer requires at least 48 hours so I will do it later.
